# Publishing dist directory to remote repo

Tags: yaml, github-actions, yarnpkg, cicd

I  have been trying to create a `build-deploy.yml` file to install my dependencies and create a `dist/` directory from `yarn build` in my remote GitHub repo.

This is what I have:

```
name: Publish dist directory

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf dist && yarn install

    - name: Build
      run: yarn build

    - name: Publish dist directory
      uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        publish_dir: ./dist
```

The job runs and succeeds but the main branch does not seem to have a `dist/` directory in GitHub.

I have tried using several approaches, uploading and downloading an artifact, using my action to perform git commands, and finally using `peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3` for publishing the directory

Answer (score 1):

> but the main branch does not seem to have a dist directory in github.

It is not supposed to have a `dist/` folder: that is for generated data, which are usually *not* versioned.

The `dist/` folder is created on the GitHub Action runner, and used by the "Publish dist directory" step to deploy its content in the associated GitHub Pages site.

The [`peaceiris/actions-gh-pages`](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages) action which does that will use the `gh_pages` branch as a default publication source.

Check if your repository does have a `gh-pages` branch updated by this action.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages/main/images/log_success.jpg]

Comment: Thanks @VonC  the peaceiris/actions-gh-pages action is definitely incorrect then.   For more context I have a small component library that is being temporarily  imported into other applications by referring it's GitHub https address rather than an npm or yarn install.   Ultimately I will publish to GitHub npm packages as a private package.    For the time being the Dist folder serves as an entry point for other apps using this library and is the reason I have it even pushed to the remote repo.

Comment: If I can set up my package.json so the index within dist isn't my entry point (compiled via TS config) that would be great too.   But at the moment pushing up a dist folder is how I know to handle this.   For the GitHub action, I can see that the build command finished successfully when I push to main but the folder isn't added to the branch.

Comment: @Pasq "I have a small component library that is being temporarily imported into other applications by referring its GitHub HTTPS address rather than a npm or yarn install. Ultimately, I will publish to GitHub NPM packages as a private package." OK, that explains why you need dist indeed. I do not know if the `peaceiris/actions-gh-pages` action is "definitely" incorrect, but it operates under a different assumption, one where you declare your dependencies rather than actually importing them.